# Excel formula: Left & function Right

Tags: excel

Good day all, 
I'm trying to chop off 9 characters starting from the right in a cell, 
when I use the "RIGHT FUNCTION" excel returns the 9 characters chopped off from the right. But I want excel to chop off 9 characters from the right and return the remaining characters to the left. However, I can't achieve this with the "LEFT FUNCTION" because the number of characters to the left varies. Please i need the exact function to chop off 9 characters from the right and the remaining characters to the left will be returned to Cell E5 
Example below:
Cell E3 = "HP Deskjet 1510 series (Copy 1) on Ne14:"
I need to chop off " on Ne14:" and return "HP Deskjet 1510 
series (Copy 1)" to Cell E5. 
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(E3,LEN(E3)-9),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done some network and server administration so I'm not sure whether snipping off the last 9 characters would be universally sufficient for a truncation rule. In my experience, networked printer locations could vary in length but the *<space>**on**<space>* portion of the full location descriptor would not.

```
=TRIM(LEFT(E3, IFERROR(FIND(" on ", E3), LEN(E3))))
```